# C program that connects to remote host and then executes system commands

Tags: c, ssh, terminal

I've looked around online about executing system commands through a c program, but none of them touched on executing the command after connecting to a remote host such as (this connection prompts for a user password):

```
 sprintf(buffer1,"ssh -l %s %s ",userName,hostName);
 system((char*)buffer1);

 //Nothing below this executes because the connection has been established

 sprintf(buffer2,"shasum sfin.exe > t.sha");
 system((char*)buffer2);
```

Once the connection is closed the program then continues to execute, is there a simple way to keep the execution going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use the function `popen` instead of `system`.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

It runs a command, returning a file object that you can write to with functions like fprintf, fwrite, etc., and those commands will go through the ssh process to the remote computer.